# Linked server Informix driver mismatch error on driver and applciation

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, odbc, informix

I tried to read all the questions here that has been asked before, but could not find any clue on my problem.

I'm trying to setup a linked server to connect on INFORMIX server, I installed the driver, i configured it on the 32Bit odbc, connection was successful, how ever when i tried to create a linked server I bumped into this error

****OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CMS_MY" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CMS_MY".****

any idea what i missed and any configuration that I look into? 
I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just making sure, both 32 and 64 bit odbc is named "odbcad32" and can be confusing. Would be nice to double check :)

Comment: µicro$oft wrote in 2007: "MSDASQL is becoming deprecated. It will not be ported to 64 bit platforms, ..." (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2007/11/10/msdasql-oledb-provider-for-odbc-drivers/).  Is there nothing better to connect to Informix?  IBM suggests ifxoledbc.